# Referenced assembly 'XXX' does not have a strong name though it does

Tags: .net

What can be wrong? I compiled and signed Lumisoft.Net project but when I'm referencing it I still get message that "Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'LumiSoft.Net' does not have a strong name"

When I open this assembly with Reflector I get this information:

```
// Assembly LumiSoft.Net, Version 2.0.4025.133
Location: C:\Users\sandrejev\Microsoft Robotics Dev Studio 2008 R3\samples\SimulationTutorials\Beginner\EmailReader\Libs\LumiSoft.Net.dll 
Name: LumiSoft.Net, Version=2.0.4025.133, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e151431d7029870f 
Type: Library
```

So I'm pretty sure I haven't missed anything

**Update**
Actually when I add reference of LumiSoft.Net.dll into Lumisoft.Net project it is recognized as signed

Comment: Is there any chance you still have the unsigned dll somewhere in the tree, or that another project in the app is using the unsigned version?

Comment: Great hint. Microsoft Robotics Dev Studio was doing some postbuild actions by copying referenced assemblies into it's binary directory. After I removed that copy (unsigned) and re-added the assembly it worked as a charm. By the way add this as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Since Marc has not created an answer and years have past, Sergej please create an answer and accept it, thanks!